# number line with different interval

Tags: formatting, overleaf, code, line-numbering

I'm new to the latex and I'm wondering how I can create a number line with different interval and labeled letter like this:[image]

Comment: Hello! For future questions try to provide some code for others to work with. It enhances the chances to get a good answer. https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: I am afraid most (if not all) tags given to the question are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start with something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
\draw(0,0) -- (10,0);

\node at (1,-1) {0};
\draw(1,0.2) -- (1,-0.2);

\node at (2,-1) {$\dfrac{1}{q}$};
\draw(2,0.2) -- (2,-0.2);

\node at (3,-1) {$\dfrac{2}{q}$};
\draw(3,0.2) -- (3,-0.2);

\node at (4.5,-1) {$\dfrac{P}{q}$};
\draw(4.5,0.2) -- (4.5,-0.2);

\node at (5,1) {P};
\draw(5,0.2) -- (5,-0.2);

\node at (6,-1) {$\dfrac{P+1}{q}$};
\draw(6,0.2) -- (6,-0.2);

\node at (10.5,0) {L};

\end{tikzpicture}

.
\end{document}
```

[image]